# How to use flutter photo_view package with local files

Tags: image, flutter

How can I provide flutter [photo_view](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/photo_view) with FileImage as an imageProvider as I want to show images from a local documents directory? The examples show Image.network sample code but I need to load images from the device.

Answer (score 2):

PhotoView receives an image provider, which can be an FileImage

```
PhotoView(
 imageProvider: FileImage("assets/uhlala.jpg")
)
```

Comment: I don't know why you were downvoted, it worked perfectly for me. Thanks.